# MySQL callbacks and scope

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, api, express

I'm having issues using `node-mysql` to build a web API using `express`. I have the following file, ./lib/handlers/list.js, which is loaded and everything just fine (using `require('./lib/handlers/list.js')(app)`):

```
var error= function(res){
  res.json([]);
}

var send_lists = function(res,lists){
    res.json(lists);
}

var add_tasks_to_lists = function(res,lists){
    for (var i = 0, list; i < lists.length, list=lists[i]; i++) {
        var connect=require('../../mysql.js').connection();
            connect.connect();
            connect.query("SELECT * FROM `www`.`teamli_tasks` WHERE `list_id`="+connect.escape(list['id'])+";",function(_err,_rows){
              if(!_err && _rows && _rows.length){
                var tasks=[];
                for(var j=0, _row; j < _rows.length, _row=_rows[j], _row!=null; j++){
                  var task={};
                  task['id']=_row.id;
                  task['text']=_row.text;
                  task['completed']=_row.completion?true:false;
                  tasks.push(task);
                }
                list['tasks']=tasks;
              }
            });
    }
    send_lists(res,lists);
}

module.exports = function(app){
  app.post('/api/list',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session);
    if(req.hasOwnProperty("body") && req.body && req.hasOwnProperty("session") && req.session && req.session.hasOwnProperty("user") && req.session.user && req.session.user.hasOwnProperty("id") && req.session.user.id){
      var connection=require('../../mysql.js').connection();
      connection.connect();
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM `www`.`teamli_lists` WHERE `owner_id`="+connection.escape(req.session.user.id)+";",function(err, rows){
        if(!err && rows && rows.length){
          var lists=[];
          for (var i = 0, row; i < rows.length, row=rows[i]; i++) {
            console.log("Getting list with ID: "+row.id);
            var list={};
            list['participants']=req.session.user.username;
            list['timeenforcer']=null;
            list['id']=row.id;
            list['date']=1382659200;
            list['duedate']=null;
            list['title']=row.name;
            list['color']=row.color;
            console.log(list);
            lists.push(list);
          }
        add_tasks_to_lists(res,lists);
        }else error(res);
      });
    }else error(res);
  });
}
```

However, when this API endpoint is hit (/api/list), I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'tasks' of undefined
    at Query._callback (/var/www/main/www/lib/handlers/api/list.js:24:27)
```

`require('../../mysql.js').connection()` yields a new `node-mysql` Connection object, set up with credentials supplied in mysql.js. Both teamli_lists and teamli_tasks have relevant data in them, connected by `id`/`list_id`.

I'm a bit new to Node, especially asynchronous stuff like this, so any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Comment: not the answer, but you should release the conections.https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#terminating-connections

Comment: @3boll Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working properly - I still have to release the connections, I know, and tidy up the code in general, but this works for now:

```
var lists=[];
var lists_count;

var error= function(res){
  res.json([]);
}

var send_lists = function(res,lists){
    res.json(lists);
}

var add_list = function(res,list){
    lists.push(list);
    if(lists.length==lists_count) send_lists(res,lists);
}

var add_tasks_to_list = function(res,list,callback){
    console.log("Adding task to list: "+list);
        var connect=require('../../mysql.js').connection();
            connect.connect();
            connect.query("SELECT * FROM `www`.`teamli_tasks` WHERE `list_id`="+connect.escape(list['id'])+";",function(_err,_rows){
              if(!_err && _rows && _rows.length){
                var tasks=[];
                for(var j=0, _row; j < _rows.length, _row=_rows[j], _row!=null; j++){
                  var task={};
                  task['id']=_row.id;
                  task['text']=_row.text;
                  task['completed']=_row.completion?true:false;
                  tasks.push(task);
                }
                list['tasks']=tasks;
              }
                callback(res,list);
            });
}

module.exports = function(app){
  app.post('/api/list',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session);
    if(req.hasOwnProperty("body") && req.body && req.hasOwnProperty("session") && req.session && req.session.hasOwnProperty("user") && req.session.user && req.session.user.hasOwnProperty("id") && req.session.user.id){
      var connection=require('../../mysql.js').connection();
      connection.connect();
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM `www`.`teamli_lists` WHERE `owner_id`="+connection.escape(req.session.user.id)+";",function(err, rows){
        if(!err && rows && rows.length){
            lists_count=rows.length;
          for (var i = 0, row; i < rows.length, row=rows[i]; i++) {
            console.log("Getting list with ID: "+row.id);
            var list={};
            list['participants']=req.session.user.username;
            list['timeenforcer']=null;
            list['id']=row.id;
            list['date']=1382659200;
            list['duedate']=null;
            list['title']=row.name;
            list['color']=row.color;
            add_tasks_to_list(res,list,add_list);
          }
        }else error(res);
      });
    }else error(res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the property 'tasks' is being used on an undefined variable. The place you are trying to set the 'tasks' property is here:

```
list['tasks']=tasks;
```

But you list is never initialized when declared in the for-loop. Try `list = {};` (an empty object)

Comment: On the contrary, my loop is defined as `for (var i = 0, list; i < lists.length, list=lists[i]; i++)`, so `list` should be set to `lists[i]`, no?

Comment: I missed that, though can't say for sure what happens when putting it there. I've always used the second statement of a for-loop as conditionals of the loop running, not as "code to run before the next execution". Perhaps try putting the `list = lists[i]` inside the for-loop? I can only see the "tasks" property used once, and if the error is about an unassigned variable, then we need to make sure it is assigned.

Comment: I fixed that problem, but now the code appears to not be adding tasks before sending the lists (probably since the call to `send_lists` is outside the asynchronous(?) MySQL code). I thought perhaps I should check if i==lists.length, but that'll still be called before the tasks have finished being added.

Comment: Correct, the `send_lists()` call should be inside the `function(err, rows)`, as that **is** being called asynchronously. So you only want to send when that is complete.

Comment: If this was the answer, you should select it as the answer.